# Another Syntax that is not Subscribe

Tags: angular

Goal:
Retrieve data.

Problem:
Is there another approach to retrieve data instead of using syntax code "subscribe"?

Info:
I'm new in Angular

```
Component.ts

this._testService.SentApplicationByIdPersonprofileid(personprofilid).subscribe(data => {
      this._sentApplicationByIdPersonprofileid = data as SentApplicationByIdPersonprofileid[];
    });    



service.ts

SentApplicationByIdPersonprofileid(id: number)
{
    return this._http.get(url + 'api/SentApplicationByIdPersonprofileid/' + id);
}



asp.net core API

public ActionResult<IEnumerable<SentApplicationByIdPersonprofileid>> SentApplicationByIdPersonprofileid(int id)
{
....
....
....
}
```

Comment: https://angular.io/api/common/AsyncPipe

Answer (score 0):

It's the easiest way you can get data. Every Observer pattern follow pub/sub design pattern fore or behind the scenes. Like in redux you don't explicity type subscribe to get data but that what happens redux writes the subscribe for you behind the scenes. A better way for larger applications is to use ngrx/store. Where you normally don't use the subscribe method , but dispatch the actions and ngrx calls the subscribe for you.

heres the link for ngrx/store:
https://ngrx.io/guide/store